# Posting XML through cURL using --data-binary

Tags: curl

I have this really typical problem. I have an XML file that I have to post to a server. I was told by the network engineer of that site to use the cURL function. The function that he provided to me was...

```
curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567
```

When I run this command I keep getting the error "Bad URL, returning 400 status"

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while now and I am getting seriously frustrated. I have tried running...

```
curl http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567
```

and I am getting a response from the machine "Test Message" along with some identification parameters of the host system. What this would probably mean that the URL of the destination is OK and it is being accessed via the cURL command.

Are there any special requirements for sending XML files via --data-binary?
Does the XML need to be formatted in a special way?
Is the syntax of the cURL command incorrect?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to quote url: `curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml "http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567"`?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I did. I tried both double as well as single quotes. I even tried using '\&' instead of '&'. The funny thing is that if I change the URL slightly, and make it curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml "http://1.2.3.4/httpgateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567" (Changed 'gateway' to 'httpgateway'), I do not get the Bad URL error anymore. I now get a 404 Not Found error, which probably means that the error has something to do with the URL rather than the syntax of the cURL command. Any thoughts on what could be going on? Is the 400 error server generated?

Comment: Did you try: `curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml -d "source=FOO&conversationid=1234567" http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit`

Comment: Thanks, Letzia! I do remember trying curl --data-binary @/opt/somefile.xml --data-binary source=FOO&conversationid=1234567 h t t p : //1.2.3.4/gateway/submit; but to no effect. Of course I did not add the quotes around the "source-FOO..." and I used --data-binary instead of just '-d'. I will try this out Monday and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read well your comment. The error you got `404 Not found` means that you reach server but page was not found, in other word, url doesn't match any resource on server. The first error was a curl error and double quote url fix it.

Comment: Hi! The `404 not found` error I got was when I changed the /gateway/ to /httpgateway/ in the cURL command. Since the /httpgateway/ page did not exist, it shot a 404 Error. This was just to ensure that syntactically the command was okay.

Comment: Okey so I guess there is something wrong in request, you should check with network engineer of that site if your url and --data-bynary option are correct. When I send xml via curl, I usually use this command: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @/opt/somefile.xml "http://1.2.3.4/gateway/submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567"` and that works, but depends on what server want :)

Comment: Thank you Letizia! I really appreciate the support. I will try running the cRUL with the mentioned options and code. I will let you know how that panned out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. The answer to this question was given early on in the discussion by Letizia but the problem was in the Syntax of the URL that I was passing. Apparently, the

> ...submit?source=FOO&conversationid=1234567

But in actuality I need to pass 'I' (Capital I, instead of small i). It was a typo error and that took more than a week to resolve!

However, the command was wrong otherwise as well because the 'quotes' (Single Quotes) were missing.